# how to select childern elements by id using parent element id in css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, parent-child

I want to select very nested child element by its id using the parent element id
    Is there an id and id selector combination in css?

```
<section id="something" class="some">
    <div>
        ...
        <div>
            <h4 id="target">Test</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

i tried like this

```
#something h4#target{     
    display:"none";
}
```

Comment: Just remove h4 and correct your css property [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/y0Lafx9y/)

Comment: Great! If it worked...

Answer (score 0):

You cant have more than one element with the same id. consider using class.

```
#something > .target{
   display:none;
}
```

Remove quotes around 'none' in your css

Comment: this id only meant for that.i wont use it again i guess.so thats ok.and thanks.